# How to write to Blob Storage in Azure SQL Server using TSql?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm creating a stored procedure which gets executed when a CSV is uploaded to Blob Storage. This file is then processed using TSQL and wish to write the result to a file

I have been able to read a file and process it using DATA_SOURCE, database scoped credential and external data source. I'm however stuck on writing the output back to a different blob container. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If it was me, I'd use Azure Data Factory, you can create a pipeline that's activated when a file is added to a blob, have it import that file, run an SP and export the results to a blob.

That maybe an Azure function that is activated on changes to a blob container.

Comment: I agree with this answer, a Logic App is an alternative too.

Comment: Yea, that's what I've seen but my manager doesn't want that as he's got an open ticket that hasn't been dealt with for about a month where there's some weird bug going on. I've also realised I can just return the data in a stored procedure so when the Azure function runs, I can write that result into a blob?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-output?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp